# Get string with PHP regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like this

> France Gros Frère et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5
>   **Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness** http: // (www). example. com/23232

I want to extract the string after the `8.5` (In bold) we can use `#wwww` and  `#bbbbb` they will remain as it is, without even change in number of characters.

This `8.5` can change it can be anything even a `7` or `3.2` etc.

Also how can i exclude a url from the end of the string ?

What is the best way to achieve this with minimum risk of error ?

Comment: @Anirudh i have an idea of exploding with `#bbbbb` and do something. I expect erros there, so i am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick & Dirty:

```
\#w+ \#b+ \d+(?:\.?\d+)? (.*)
```

Example:

```
<?php  
$string = "France Gros Frère et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5 Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness";  
$regex = "/\#w+ \#b+ \d+(?:\.?\d+)? (.*)/";  
preg_match ($regex, $string, $output);

echo $output[1];
?>
```

But if there can be a string WITHOUT any number after #bbbbb, you better use this:

```
\#w+ \#b+\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\s*(.*)
```

So you don't have to put any number after #bbbbb and you can use as many spaces as you like between #bbbbb, the number (if there's any) and the string you want to extract.

Most of it is optional, so your string could look like this:

> blabla #w #bb Hello World

Or like this

> blabla #wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww #bbb 1337 Hello World

Or like this:

> #w #bHello World

---

You can see the result [here](http://regexp-tester.mediacix.de/t536)

EDIT:

As requested, this one should also remove URLs inside of the string:

```
<?php  
$string = "France Gros Frère et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5 Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness http://www.example.com/23232";  
$regex = "/\#w+ \#b+ \d+(?:\.?\d+)? (.*)/";  
preg_match ($regex, $string, $output);

if (isset($output[1])) {
    $regex = "!https?:\/\/(?:[\da-z\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z\.]{2,6})(?:[\/\w \.-]*)*\/?!";  
    $newString = trim(preg_replace ($regex, '', $output[1]));

    echo $newString;
} else {
    echo $string;
}
?>
```

The result should be:

> Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness

Comment: Also how can i exclude a url from the end of the string ?

Comment: Do you want to exclude every URL or just specific URLs?

Comment: Every URL from the end of string

Answer (score 2):

Use simple regex

```
$a='France Gros FrÃ¨re et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5 Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness';

preg_match('/\#bbbbb [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ (.*)/', $a, $match);

print_r($match);
```

`[0-9]+` - is a number at least one or more

`(.*)` - is a subpattern for any character that goes after number.

`echo $match[1];` prints what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will:

- capture the entire string upto the url at the end, so the url can be excluded if it exists
- capture the number after `#wwww #bbbbb`
- allow the number to contain one or less decimal points

`(.*?\#wwww\s\#bbbbb\s((?:\d+\.)?\d+).*?)(https?:\/\/\S*)?$`

[image]

## PHP Example

**Sample Text**

`France Gros Frère et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5 Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness http://www.example.com/23232`

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match('/(.*?\#wwww\s\#bbbbb\s((?:\d+\.)?\d+).*?)(https?:\/\/\S*)?$/imx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Capture Groups**

0 has the entire string
1 has the entire string excluding the url at the end if it exists
2 has the desired number
3 has the url

```
[0] => France Gros Frère et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5 Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness http://www.example.com/23232
[1] => France Gros Frère et Sur Hte-Cote de Nuit Blc 2008 #wwww #bbbbb 8.5 Nice yellow fruit nose, some vanilla notes, good crispness 
[2] => 8.5
[3] => http://www.example.com/23232
```